# twitpic integration with iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, integration, twitpic

I want to upload image to twitter using twit pic. I am using Oauth method.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you not try with share kit? its easy way to upload picture to twitter.

Comment: I am working on it right now as I havnt use it before? but you sure twitpic will be resolved by sharekit?

Comment: Yes there is no need to share picture via twitpic its harder option rather than implement share kit.

Comment: My main requirement is there is a image in app and it should be shared on twitter as a image, so I search and found that we can share image via twit pic? so I used it nut there are authentication issues with that. I am checking with share kit? but I can concerning that share kit is able to share image on twitter?

Comment: Yes dude its damn easy option to share photo/video to facebook & twitter.Try it its easily be implemented also.

Comment: Thanks Man, I am working on it and lets see how it goes

Comment: Its ok.Best of luck.I know you can do it very well.